# Calling a variable without a space before it in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use variables from a imported CSV file to substitute variables in a string.

Here's the code.

`param( [string] $CSV)
$VMs = Import-Csv $CSV
Foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
psexec \\$VM.VM_Name -h netsh interface ip set address name='"Local Area Connection"' static $VM.IP_Address 255.255.255.0 $VM.Gateway 1
}`

this is what it returns:

psexec \@{VM_Name=TESTCSVVM; IP_Address=10.12.81.82; Gateway=10.12.81.1; VLAN=H
Q_VM_81}.VM_Name -h netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection"
static 10.12.81.82 255.255.255.0 10.12.81.1 1

Here's what I want it to look like:

psexec \TESTCSVVM -h netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection"
static 10.12.81.82 255.255.255.0 10.12.81.1 1

Here's the CSV file:

"VM_Name","IP_Address","Gateway","VLAN"
"TESTCSVVM","10.12.81.82","10.12.81.1","HQ_VM_81"

How do I make sure theres no space between the \ and the 1st variable $VM.VM_Name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    psexec \\\\$($VM.VM_Name) -h netsh interface ip set address `
        name='"Local Area Connection"' `
        static $VM.IP_Address 255.255.255.0 $VM.Gateway 1 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, generally wrapping variables in quotes will work too.

So if:

```
$path = C:\Windows\
$File = MyFile.ext
write-host "$path$File
```

Would look like:

```
C:\Windows\myFile.ext
```